# Balthazar, 'Caspar' and Melchior

Tags: names, christmas

The names traditionally given to the three Wise Men are *Balthazar*, *Caspar* and *Melchior*. But a friend of mine told me that in Australian English *Caspar* is not used. They use, instead, *Gasper*. Can anybody confirm, giving contestually some historical reason.

Comment: Where have you looked for the answer? (Just so others don't waste their time repeating your research)

Comment: (I think you might have your second syllables switched around: I usually see *CaspEr* and *GaspAr*.) This might be related to how in Latin, the cognomen *Gaius* is abbreviated *C.* The two sounds *are* closely related - one is just the voiceless version of the other.

Comment: This question can be improved by doing your research, showing the results in your question, and explaining what it is you still need explained.

Comment: I've voted to close as Too Localised. It's not General Reference, since it now seems that even Wikipedia just makes things up about which is "more common". But the spelling of such obscure historical proper names is not what I consider of general interest to future visitors here. Strictly speaking, it's probably Off Topic.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=gaspar) only adds that "Jasper [is the] English form of *Caspar* or of *Gaspar*, the traditional name of one of the Three Kings". It would probably take a biblical historian to trace all the variations that occur in the literature.  Suffice it to say, Gasper and Caspar are both in common use (I've even seen both in video games, which may qualify as "mass media") and have been for some time.

Comment: I would guess "Caspar" is an older form from the time when Romans wrote the sound /g/ with the letter "C." This can also be seen in the name Gaius, which was spelled "Caius" before the introduction of the letter "G" (and continued to be abbreviated with "C" even after that).

Answer (score 3):

From the Wikipedia entry on the [biblical magi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Magi):

> Traditions identify a variety of different names for the Magi. In the Western Christian church they have been commonly known as:
>
> - Melchior (also Melichior), a Persian scholar
> - Caspar (also Gaspar, Jaspar, Jaspas, Gathaspa, and other variations), an Indian scholar
> - Balthazar (also Balthasar, Balthassar, and Bithisarea), an Arabian scholar
>
> Caspar is also sometimes given as Gaspar or Jaspar. One candidate for the origin of the name Caspar appears in the Acts of Thomas as Gondophares (AD 21 – c.AD 47), i.e., Gudapharasa (from which 'Caspar' might derive as corruption of 'Gaspar').

Following on to the entry on the name [Casper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_%28name%29):

> By the 6th century, the name Gaspar was recorded in mosaic at the Basilica of Sant'Apollinare Nuovo in Ravenna, Italy as one of the traditional names assigned by folklore to the anonymous Magi mentioned in the Gospel of Matthew account of the Nativity of Jesus. The letter "G" in the name Gaspar was clearly different than the letter "C" used elsewhere, suggesting that the name Gaspar preceded the name Caspar, and not the other way around as some have supposed.
>
> The Western tradition of the name Gaspar also derives from an early 6th Century Greek manuscript, translated into the Latin "Excerpta Latina Barbari". A pseudo-Venerable Beda text, called "Collectanea et Flores", apparently continues the tradition of the name Caspar: "Secundus nomine Caspar" (P.L., XCIV, 541). This text is said to be from the 8th or 9th century, of Irish origin. As a surname, Gaspar survives today in Spanish, Portuguese and French, although the latter adds a silent d. It also survives in the Armenian name, Gasparian.

It would thus appear that the variants have a long history in Europe and would have followed British colonists, prisoners, etc. to Australia.

Comment: I think that Wikipedia article is misleading when it says *"Caspar is also **sometimes** given as Gaspar or Jaspar"*. Searching Google Books, I find 614 hits for ["Caspar and Melchior"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Caspar+and+Melchior%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but 637 for ["**Gaspar** and Melchior"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Gaspar+and+Melchior%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (*Jaspar/Jasper* get only 11 between them). So in fact, *Gasper* is (admittedly, by a whisker) the most common form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Likewise for some of the Balthazar variations. The last one, "Bithisarea", is completely unfamiliar to me and doesn't have any hits in any of the [online corpora](http://corpus.byu.edu/) I tried.

Comment: It was also unfamiliar to me. That's why I didn't include it in the search string, because any particular variant would just reduce my results count to no purpose. Incidentally, when I [reverse my search terms](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Melchior+and+Caspar%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), **Gaspar** is the [runaway winner](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Melchior+and+Gaspar%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) by 1470 to 943. Wikipedia is *really* misleading about prevalence.

Comment: pseudo-Venerable Bede? as opposed to the genuinely-Venerable Bede?

Comment: @StoneyB I think it is the text that is pseudo-, i.e. it probably wasn't written by Bede of Northumbria, despite having been attributed to him.